# JAXL 3. Shutting down

Tags: php, xmpp

I'm tryinig to use jaxl 3.0 for notifications over xmpp. The only thing, i can't undersdand  - how i can shutdown JAXL server, after job is done?. A can`t see any callbacks for stopping jaxl-server

Here is part of my code

```
   public function __construct(JAXL $jaxl){
     $this->client=$jaxl;
     $this->client->add_cb('on_auth_success', array($this,'send'));
   }

   public function setSenders($senders){
       $this->senders=$senders;
   }
   public function addLine($messagePart){
        $this->message.=$messagePart.PHP_EOL;
   }

   public function notify(){
      $this->client->start();
   }

   public function send(){
   foreach($this->senders as $sender){
      $this->client->send_chat_msg($sender,$this->message);
    }
    //Here server should be stopped. Everything is done.
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$client->send_end_stream();` where `$client` is JAXL instance. This will send xmpp stream end packet. You can also register callback for `on_disconnect` event which is called when JAXL instance has successfully closed the connection with the server. See [examples/echo_bot.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/echo_bot.php#L107) for more detail (it make use of both of these).